# Como hago una condicion para marcar todo o marcar un solo RadioButton? Android Studio

Tags: android, botón, radiobutton, radio, radiogroup

Yo Quiero hacer una app que me de una opción de poder marcar todos los `radiobutton` y otra opcion que me deje solo apretar uno, así que hice un `radiogroup` y pensé en habilitarlo para que marque solo uno, y deshabilitarlo cuando quiero que marque todo, pero cuando hice el código en deshabilitar no me dejaba marcar nada... 
Mi codigo en XML:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="138dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Radio 1"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Radio 2"
        android:textSize="30dp" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/enablebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="109dp"
    android:text="Establecer is Enabled" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondisable"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:text="Disable" />
```

Mi codigo en Java:

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);

        final Button changeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enablebutton);
        final Button disable= findViewById(R.id.buttondisable);

        //Habilitar y deshabilitar RADIOGROUP

        for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(true);
        }


        //Boton para activar Radiogroup

        changeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setRadioGroupEnabled(radiogroup, true);//enable RadioGroup


            }
        });

        //Boton para desactivar radiogroup
        disable.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                setRadioGroupEnabled(radiogroup, false);

            }
        });



    }
    //Metodo de colocar enabled el Radiogroup

    private void setRadioGroupEnabled(RadioGroup radiogroup, boolean b) {


        for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
            ((RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(b);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Dentro de un RadioGroup, solo se permite seleccionar un único elemento.

Answer (score 2):

Es importante saber que el uso de [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup) se especifica para exclusión múltiple, por lo tanto únicamente un elemento dentro del grupo puede estar seleccionado:

> [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup): Esta clase se usa para crear un ámbito de **exclusión múltiple para** un
>   conjunto de botones de opción. Al marcar un botón de radio que
>   pertenece a un grupo de radio, se desmarca cualquier botón de opción
>   previamente seleccionado dentro del mismo grupo. Inicialmente, todos
>   los botones de radio están desmarcados. Si bien no es posible
>   desmarcar un botón de opción en particular, el grupo de radio puede
>   eliminarse para eliminar el estado verificado.

Por lo tanto puedes seleccionar un `radioButton` mediante el método `setChecked(true)`, ya que `setEnabled()` se usa para habilitar/deshabilitar la vista.

Pero solo se podría seleccionar un elemento, aún usando el siguiente bucle:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < radiogroup.getChildCount(); i++) {
     ((RadioButton) radiogroup.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);
 }
```

se obtendría el último elemento seleccionado contenido dentro del [RadioGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Si deseas seleccionar varios elementos, usarias unicamente `RadioButtons` pero no contenidos dentro de un `RadioGroup` o puedes usar [Checkbox](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox)** que es destinado para este propósito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]